# How to detect if an item exist in treeview

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

I have few lines of code here to detect if an item already exist in `tkinter treeview` before selected item can be inserted in the `tree2` .If the item already exist it should print `"item exist"` if not the item should be inserted.

```
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk


blow = [("january", "2013"),("february", "2014"),("march", "2015"),("april", "2016"),("may", "2017")]

def append_select():
    cur_id = tree.focus()

    for child in tree2.selection():
    #for child in tree2.get_children():
        if cur_id in child:
            print("item exist")
        elif cur_id:
            tree2.insert("", tk.END, values=tree.item(cur_id)['values'])


root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")

tree = ttk.Treeview(columns=("columns1", "columns"), show="headings", selectmode="browse")
tree.heading("#1", text="Month")
tree.heading("#2", text="Year")
for n in blow:
    tree.insert("", tk.END, values=(n))
tree.pack()

b1 = tk.Button(text="append", command=append_select)
b1.pack()

tree2 = ttk.Treeview(columns=("Month", "Year"), show="headings")
tree2.heading("#1", text="month")
tree2.heading("#2", text="year")
tree2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: There's no pre-builded functionality for such case, but you can rely on treeview's tags - specify tag as an item value for each item and search via `tag_has` (related: [treeview docs](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk-Treeview.html), [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46217978/6634373)). If tags not an option - feel free to use [a common loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17225920/python-tkinter-treeview-searchable) thru treeview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched the item text in treeview to check duplication.

```
def search(treeview, comparevalue):
    children = treeview.get_children('')
    for child in children:
        values = treeview.item(child, 'values')
        if comparevalue[0]==values[0] and str(comparevalue[1])==str(values[1]):
            return True
    return False

def append_select():
    cur_id = tree.focus()
    selvalue = tree.item(cur_id)['values']
    print('append_select:', cur_id, selvalue)

    if search(tree2, selvalue)==True:
        print("item exist")
    elif cur_id:
        tree2.insert("", tk.END, values=selvalue)
```

But more simply can worked by using item iid.

```
def append_select():
    cur_id = tree.focus()
    selvalue = tree.item(cur_id)['values']
    if tree2.exists(cur_id)==True:
        print("item exist")
    elif cur_id:
        tree2.insert("", tk.END, cur_id,  values=selvalue)
```

Comment: can you explain how you came out with that.

Comment: in your append_select() code, tree2.selection() is always empty. you should use tree.selection().